# How to mark words that match words from a list in a django form's textarea using javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

I have the following form:

```
class TestForm(Form):
    testfield = CharField(widget=Textarea(attrs={'rows': 10, 'id': 'test'}), label='Input test text here')
```

Rendered to my template along with the following list as context:

```
dummy_list = ['hi', 'hello']
```

I'm trying to make a button which I can click in my template which makes words in the form bold if they are contained within the list.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Mark_words(id)
{
    var form_content = document.getElementById(id);
    var dummylist = {{ dummy_list|safe }}
    var new_form_content = ""
    for(var x in form_content.value) {
        if ( dummylist.indexOf(x) > -1 ){
            x = x.bold();
            new_form_content += x + " ";
        } else  {
            new_form_content += x + " ";
        }

    }
    form_content.innerText = new_form_content;
}
</script>
```

And the following button:

```
<button type = "submit" class ="btn btn-info" value = "Click" onclick="Mark_words('test')">Mark words</button>
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens when I click the button. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

Initially, nothing happened because the template escaped the string. Adding the built-in template filter "|safe" solved this. However - now the textarea is just filled with numbers when I press the button:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133
```

Comment: what does the javascript look like when it's rendered?

Comment: It looks identical to the above with one exception:
{{ dummy_list ]]is rendered as [&#x27;hi&#x27;, &#x27;hello&#x27;]

So I guess the problem is here?

Comment: Yes. The termplate engine is escaping the string. (It's expecting to be outputting HTML not JS) I think there is thing you can do to turn of escaping...

Comment: Found it - I can add a "safe" tag in the template. But now the output is just numbers - will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you're iterating through the content of the `textarea`.

`for(var x in form_content.value)` will iterate through the content one character at a time and because you're using [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#array_iteration_and_for...in), you'll get the indices of the characters, not the characters themselves.

What you need to do is split the string on spaces, so you're iterating through words, and change `in` to [`of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) so you get the string and not the index of the string:

```js
for(var x of form_content.value.split(' '))
```

```js
function Mark_words(id)
{
    var form_content = document.getElementById(id);
    var dummylist = ['hi', 'hello'];
    var new_form_content = ""
    for(let x of form_content.value.split(' ')) {
        if ( dummylist.indexOf(x) > -1 ){
            x = x.bold();
            new_form_content += x + " ";
        } else  {
            new_form_content += x + " ";
        }

    }
    form_content.innerText = new_form_content;
}
```

```html
<button type = "submit" class ="btn btn-info" value = "Click" onclick="Mark_words('test')">Mark words</button>
<textarea id="test">hello there I am a new type of automated washing machine</textarea>
```